# How to add tags to image with Powershell

Tags: image, powershell, tags

I have created a small powershell script to extract images from SQL server DB (stored in varbinary) to files in a server. It works perfectly! The problem is that I want to add tags to these .jpeg files based on their info in the database. I didn't find any solution on the web. Is there Powershell gurus out there, I need your help :-)

Thanks,

Sabrina

```
$SqlBH = "MYSQLQUERY"
# Open DB Connection 
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +
"Integrated Security=False;" +
"Initial Catalog=$Database; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;";
$con.Open();

# New Command and Reader
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $SqlBH, $con;
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();

# Create a byte array for the stream.
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)

# Looping through records
While ($rd.Read())
{
Write-Output ("Exporting file: {0} ParentID: {1}" -f 
$rd.GetString(0),$rd.GetString(2));
# New BinaryWriter

# Create parent folder if not present
$fl = $rd.GetString(2)
$Destfl = $Dest + $fl
$FileExists = Test-Path $Destfl
If ($FileExists -eq $False) {new-item $Destfl -itemtype directory}

$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Destfl + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, 
Write;
$bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;

$start = 0;
$received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
While ($received -gt 0)
{
$bw.Write($out, 0, $received);
$bw.Flush();
$start += $received;
$received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
}

$bw.Close();
$fs.Close();
}

# Closing & Disposing all objects
$fs.Dispose();
$rd.Close();
$cmd.Dispose();
$con.Close();

Write-Output ("Finished");
```

Comment: Please provide the powershell code so others can review it and provide you with an answer.

Comment: Edit you question with you code, don't paste in comment please

Answer (score 2):

Already some struggling, I've implemented the following solution. I hope it can help someone sometime :-)

Based on the library Exiv 2 (http://www.exiv2.org/), I've added following code after line 70 ($fs.Close();) :

```
# Tag images
$cmd_exe '.\exiv2.exe'
$arg1 = '-M'
$arg2_BH = """add Iptc.Application2.Keywords String " + $rd.GetString(3) + """"
$arg2_LSD = """add Iptc.Application2.Keywords String " + $rd.GetString(4) + """"
$arg2_logger = """add Iptc.Application2.Keywords String " + $rd.GetString(5) + """"
$arg3 = $Destfl + $rd.GetString(0)

& $cmd_exe $arg1 $arg2_BH $arg1 $arg2_LSD $arg1 $arg2_logger $arg3
```

That's it :-)